# Tensorflow 2: how to run a model when eager execution is disabled?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to run a tensorflow model, under tensorflow 2, when eager execution is disabled.
For instance, assume that my model is built as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import disable_eager_execution
disable_eager_execution()
a = tf.constant(1)
b = tf.constant(2)
c = a + b
```

At this point, how do I launch the execution of the model and print the resulting value of c?
In tensorflow 1 this would be done using sessions and the run() method, but I don't know how to do it natively in tensorflow 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tf.compat.v1.Session.
I have added to your example. Here is the code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import disable_eager_execution
disable_eager_execution()

a = tf.constant(1)
b = tf.constant(2)
c = a + b

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()    
with sess.as_default():
    o = sess.run(c)
print(o)
```

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned in my question, I know how to do this by using tensorflow 1 services (which are still available in tensorflow 2 through the compat.v1 interface). I wanted to know how to do it natively.